# JQuery hidden element input issue traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree-traversal

I have a problem I just can't figure out. I have a set of DIV's which are `display: none;` by default:

```
<div id="pivot">
    <div id="leftcol">Pivot</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="030-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="pi" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="pit"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pos1">
    <div id="leftcol">Position 1</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="031-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="p1" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="p1t"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pos2">
    <div id="leftcol">Position 2</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="031-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="p2" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="p2t"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pos3">
    <div id="leftcol">Position 3</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="031-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="p3" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="p3t"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pos4">
    <div id="leftcol">Position 4</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="031-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="p4" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="p4t"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pos5">
    <div id="leftcol">Position 5</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="031-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="p5" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="p5t"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pos6">
    <div id="leftcol">Position 6</div>
    <div id="rightcol">
        <input class="small" value="031-" disabled />
        <input class="input" id="p6" maxlength="6" />
        <span id="p6t"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this code unhides the relevant section:

```
$.ajax({        
    url: "getSerial.asp",
    data: { term: term },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $('option:selected').append('-' + data[0].sn)
        $('#prefix').attr('disabled', true)
        var code = data[0].partno.substring(6, 12);
        len = code.length;
        $('#pivot').show(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (code.substr(i, 1) != "-") {
                $('#pos' + code.substr(i, 1)).show(0);
            }                   
        }
        $('div').find('input:enabled').first().focus();
    }       
});
```

So that works perfectly fine.  Then what I'm trying to do is as you type in 6 characters, it automatically jumps down to the next visible input (`class="input"`).  My code for that is very un-glamorous and works ONLY with the next logical div (pos1, pos2 etc).  The combination may be pos1,pos3,pos3 so missing out number 2 (as it is still hidden).

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('div').next('div').find('.input:visible').focus()
```

This doesn't work for the above combination.  How do I traverse successfully only to the next visible .input class?

Comment: I suggest creating a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it **runnable**, removing the irrelevancies (such as the ajax), replacing them with dummy values/calls if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:has()` in the selector to match a DIV that contains a visible input.

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('div').nextAll('div:has(.input:visible)').first().find('.input:visible').focus();
```

Comment: Thanks @barmar that worked a treat!  Wasn't sure whether two parent DIV's would be an acceptable practice.

Comment: I prefer to give the grandparent a class and use `.closest('.classname')`

Comment: I've changed as suggested and works just as well and makes the code simpler, many thanks again!